# What is the location of this performance?

Tags: germany, where-on-earth, identify-this, locate-this

In [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gphiFVVtUI), Estas de Tonne is playing on a street - from what I can gather, somewhere in Germany, some time in 2011-2012, although I may be mistaken.  Can anyone pinpoint a more precise location?  If anyone knows more about when this took place, that would be a great extra bonus.

Comment: The street view is just a panorama taken from a weird ankle (on the floor) at a possibly different location (note that you can't move) and buildings are blocked from sight by the market.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clicking "show more" below the video you will read:

> The Performance of Russian guitarist Estas Tonne at the Buskers Festival Stadtspektakel in Landshut in September 2011 in the Old Town with "The Song of the Golden Dragon"..

The shoe store "Lipp" and the Commerzbank in the video give away the precise address: Altstadt 76, Landshut, Germany.

Here is a link to the website of the ["Stadtspektakel" festival](http://www.spektakel.la/). It is also shown (among others) during the last seconds of the video.

Comment: It's a pity streetview doesn't cover the Altstad. Only user-contributed photos.

Comment: @JoErNanO I suspect it's because it's normally pedestrian-only.

Comment: Ah! Why didn't I click on "show more"??

Comment: @JoErNanO: @ AleksG: Streetview in Germany has been deprecated years and years ago, so coverage in Germany is extremely limited. The way it was everywhere about 7 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

The caption of [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gphiFVVtUI) says it was shot in the old town at Landshut, Germany:

> Der Auftritt des russischen Gitarristen Estas Tonne beim Stadtspektakel in Landshut im September 2011 in der Altstadt mit dem Lied "The Song of the Golden Dragon"
>
> The Performance of Russian guitarist Estas Tonne at the Buskers Festival Stadtspektakel in Landshut in September 2011 in the Old Town with "The Song of the Golden Dragon"..